# Cardinalities of $\text{Hom}(\Bbb Z/n\Bbb Z,\Bbb Q/\Bbb Z)$ and $\text{Hom}(\Bbb Q/\Bbb Z,\Bbb Z/n\Bbb Z)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-homomorphism

> Consider $\text{Hom}(\Bbb Z/n\Bbb Z,\Bbb Q/\Bbb Z)$, and $\text{Hom}(\Bbb Q/\Bbb Z,\Bbb Z/n\Bbb Z)$. $\text{Hom}(A,B)$ is the set of all homomorphisms from $A$ to $B$, where $A,B$ are groups. Find $|\text{Hom}(\Bbb Z/n\Bbb Z,\Bbb Q/\Bbb Z)|$, and $|\text{Hom}(\Bbb Q/\Bbb Z,\Bbb Z/n\Bbb Z)|$.

So, here are my thoughts and questions. First, $\text{Hom}(\Bbb Z/n\Bbb Z,\Bbb Q/\Bbb Z)$. Consider some $f\in \text{Hom}(\Bbb Z/n\Bbb Z,\Bbb Q/\Bbb Z)$. $f$ is completely determined by $f(1) = a$, since $f$ is a homomorphism. What do elements in $\Bbb Q/\Bbb Z$ look like? I am not too comfortable with quotient groups yet. They'd be of the form $q + \mathbb Z$ where $q\in \Bbb Q$, right? Assuming this holds, I feel that $|\text{Hom}(\Bbb Z/n\Bbb Z,\Bbb Q/\Bbb Z)| = \infty$, because there are infinitely many choices of $q\in \mathbb Q$ for $q + \mathbb Z$. I know that if $q_1-q_2\in \mathbb Z$, then $q_1 + \mathbb Z = q_2 + \Bbb Z$ in $\Bbb Q/\Bbb Z$, but even then, the choices are infinite indeed - the representatives are rational numbers in $[0,1)$.

About $|\text{Hom}(\Bbb Q/\Bbb Z,\Bbb Z/n\Bbb Z)|$, consider $f\in \text{Hom}(\Bbb Q/\Bbb Z,\Bbb Z/n\Bbb Z)$. This seems tougher! For $q\in [0,1)$, I must assign values to $f(q + \mathbb Z)$ from $\{0,1,...,n-1\} \in \Bbb Z/n\Bbb Z$. I'm unable to figure out the number of ways of doing this.

Could you please drop any hints to point me in the right direction? Solutions are good too. Thank you!

---

**Update:**
Could it be the case that $\text{Hom}(\Bbb Z/n\Bbb Z,\Bbb Q/\Bbb Z) \cong \text{Hom}(\Bbb Z/n\Bbb Z,\Bbb Z/n\Bbb Z)$ in general, or at least for some $n$?

Also, on second thoughts, feels like $\text{Hom}(\Bbb Q/\Bbb Z,\Bbb Z/n\Bbb Z)$ is a singleton, i.e. $|\text{Hom}(\Bbb Q/\Bbb Z,\Bbb Z/n\Bbb Z)| = 1$ for all $n$ (consisting of only the homomorphism which maps all elements of $\Bbb Q/\Bbb Z$ to $0\in \Bbb Z/n\Bbb Z$. Is that right, and how do I show it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is much simpler than that. We have $|Hom(\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z},\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z})|=n$ and $|Hom(\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z},\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z})|=1$.
Indeed, in first case $f_k(1+n\mathbb{Z})=\frac{k}{n}+\mathbb{Z}$ is homomorphism for all $0\leq k\leq n$. Conversely, if $f$ is homomorphism and $f(1+nZ)=\frac{a}{b}+\mathbb{Z}$, where $a$ relatively
prime to $b$, then $n\frac{a}{b}\in\mathbb{Z}$ and $b$ is divisor of $n$ and $\frac{a}{b}+\mathbb{Z}=\frac{k}{n}+\mathbb{Z}$, where $k\equiv a\frac{n}{b} (\rm mod\, n)$.

In second case, if $f:\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}\rightarrow \mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ is homomorphism and $f(\frac{1}{mn})=k+n\mathbb{Z}$, then $f(\frac{1}{m})=f(n\cdot\frac{1}{mn})=nk+n\mathbb{Z}=n\mathbb{Z}$ for all $m\in\mathbb{Z}$. So, $f(\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z})=0$, where $0=n\mathbb{Z}$. That is, in this case there is a single homomorphism equal to zero

Comment: In your first paragraph, it looks like you're showing that the homomorphisms correspond to divisors of $n$, which isn't consistent with your claim at the start that there are $n$ of them. The correspondence should be $a\in\Bbb Z/n$ corresponds to the homomorphism $1\mapsto a/n$.

Comment: @KReiser, thanks for pointing out my mistake